# How to add Extra column with current date in Spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add one column in my existing Pyspark Dataframe using withColumn method.I want to insert current date in this column.From my Source I don't have any date column so i am adding this current date column in my dataframe and saving this dataframe in my table so later for tracking purpose i can use this current date column.
I am using below code

```
    df2=df.withColumn("Curr_date",datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

here df is my existing Dataframe and i want to save df2 as table with Curr_date column.
but here its expecting existing column  or lit method instead of datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d').
someone please guide me how should i add this Date column in my dataframe.?

Comment: Can you accept an answer or comment if you need something different ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use either [`lit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit) or [`current_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.current_date)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn("Curr_date", F.lit(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))

# OR

df2 = df.withColumn("Curr_date", F.current_date())
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a spark function `current_timestamp()`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('current', date_format(current_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')).show()

+----+----------+
|test|   current|
+----+----------+
|test|2020-09-09|
+----+----------+
```

Comment: why would you use current_timestamp when you want date ?

Answer (score 4):

`current_timestamp()` is good but it is evaluated during the serialization time.

If you prefer to use the `timestamp` of the processing time of a row, then you may use the below method,

```
withColumn('current', expr("reflect('java.time.LocalDateTime', 'now')"))
```